# What is the correct approach to adding classes to an array of DOM objects using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays, dom

I have tried two types of iterating techniques but both produce the same error:

> addClass is not function

First example using for:

```
function game(){
    var cards = $('.card');

    function initialize(){
        for(var x = 0; x < cards.length; x++) {    
            cards[x].addClass('wtf');    
        }
    };
};
```

Second try using each:

```
function game(){
    var cards = $('.card');

    function initialize(){
        //Add random key values to pairs of cards
        $.each( cards ,function(i, ele) {    
            ele[i].addClass('wtf');
        });
    };
};
```

What is the correct way to manipulate these type of arrays?

Comment: What about `$('.card').addClass('wtf');` jQuery goes through each one for you, you don't have to. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code examples don't work as you're attempting to call a jQuery method, `addClass`, on a DOMElement instead of a jQuery object.

The `addClass()` method will do the looping for you internally if multiple elements match the selector in the jQuery object so it's just a one-line call you need to make:

```
function game(){
    var $cards = $('.card');

    function initialize() {
        $cards.addClass('wtf');
    };
};
```

> How would I be able to select the 5th card for example and add the class to only that card?

To do that you can use the `eq()` method:

```
$cards.eq(4).addClass('wtf');
```

Note that the index is zero based, hence the 5th element is index 4.

Comment: Thanks! The above example adds the 'wtf' class to all DOMElements in the array. However how would I be able to select the 5th card for example and add the class to only that card?

Comment: You can use the `eq()` method to do that: `$cards.eq(4).addClass('wtf');` I updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

`cards[x]` is a DOM element, use `$(cards[x])` jQuery object like following.

```
function game() {
    var cards = $('.card');

    function initialize() {
        for (var x = 0; x < cards.length; x++) {
            //change following line. 
            $(cards[x]).addClass('wtf');
        }
    };
};
```

You don't need to loop through all element. You cant just use `cards .addClass('wtf')` like following.

```
function game() {
    var cards = $('.card');

    function initialize() { 
        cards.addClass('wtf');
    };
};
```

If you want select specific card then use **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** method like following.

```
cards.eq(4).addClass('wtf');   //eq(4) will select 5th card
```

Comment: Thanks Azim it looks like I can use that with a for loop to select a specific card.